# Passing URL parameter to a page in javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, url

I need help, This is what am actually trying to do. I have two files. "index.php" and "realtime.php" the index.php displays news from a particular country base on the url parameter "country_code", and the realtime.php updates the news list every 2 seconds. what I want is for realtime.php to get the current url parameter of index.php so that it can only update news from that particular country base on the url parameter. I really need this help. Thank you again.

script for index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$.arte({'ajax_url': '../realtime.php?lastid='+$('.postitem:first').attr('id'), 'on_success': update_field, 'time': 1000}).start();
function update_field(data)
{
    $("#realtimeupdate").html(data);
}
});
```

And the script  for realtime.php

```
<?php

include"customDB.php";
$lastid = $_REQUEST['lastid'];
$query = 'SELECT count(*) as newpost FROM wp_posts WHERE country_code = "XXXXX" AND    post_id > "'.$lastid.'"';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rec = mysql_fetch_object($result);
if($rec->newpost){ ?>
<a href="" id="newpostlink">(<?php echo $rec->newpost; ?>) new posts</a>
<script type="text/javascript">document.title = '(<?php echo $rec->newpost; ?>) new  posts'</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question, and you don't tell us you have tried. *An urgent edit will be greatly appreciated*.

Comment: Please describe what you need more ... I could not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand this question, you need two things:

1. A mod rewrite to pass the URL variable to your script
2. A snippet to get the variable

So, thats pretty easy. First you write something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php?country_code=(.*)$ realtime.php?country_code=$1
```

And in your realtime.php you can use `$_GET['country_code']` to use your parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, This is what am actually trying to do. I have two files. "index.php" and "realtime.php" the index.php displays news from a particular country base on the url parameter "country_code", and the realtime.php updates the news list every 2 seconds. what I want is for realtime.php to get the current URL parameter of index.php so that it can only update news from that particular country base on the URL parameter. I really need this help. Thank you again.

Comment: So you have something like two frames and the one with realtime.php have to know the URL parameters of the other one? For Javascript you could use jQuery like explained here: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html So you are able to get the values and, for example, call the realtime.php via AJAX in the background.